# How do I loop through the output of an AWS command that is a list?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

The problem that I have is that I cannot figure out how to loop through the following when there could be multiple `[1]`'s. I may have 10-15 of these `[1]`'s with corresponding `['PrivateIpAddress']` allocated to our Elastic IPs. I need to loop through, and find a public IP that is not mapped to a private IP (IOW, the private IP field must be blank).

I've tried to run a loop based on this output. Note that all number values are random for confidentiality:

```
{
    "Addresses": [
        {
            "PublicIp": "120.34.250.81",
            "AllocationId": "eipalloc-12345678901234567",
            "AssociationId": "eipassoc-12345678901234567",
            "Domain": "vpc",
            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-12345678901234567",
            "NetworkInterfaceOwnerId": "848293479",
            "PrivateIpAddress": "192.168.40.12",
            "PublicIpv4Pool": "amazon"
        },
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-10982738475698765",
            "PublicIp": "3.201.99.99",
            "AllocationId": "eipalloc-12345678901234567",
            "AssociationId": "eipassoc-12345678901234567",
            "Domain": "vpc",
            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-12345678901234567",
            "NetworkInterfaceOwnerId": "812942397874",
            "PrivateIpAddress": "44.12.3.3",
            "PublicIpv4Pool": "amazon"
        },
        {
            "PublicIp": "3.12.1.4",
            "AllocationId": "eipalloc-12897647827389876",
            "AssociationId": "eipassoc-95748298758423987",
            "Domain": "vpc",
            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-94872390876543212",
            "NetworkInterfaceOwnerId": "1209182938",
            "PrivateIpAddress": "44.12.12.12",
            "PublicIpv4Pool": "amazon"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's my code:

```
# check to see if there's a private IP assigned already
    private_ip = load_json_alloc['Addresses'][1]['PrivateIpAddress']
    i = 0
    loop = load_json_alloc['Addresses'][i]['PrivateIpAddress']

    while i < len(loop):
        print(private_ip[i])
        i += 1
    print(loop)
```

...and the print output:

```
4
4
.
9
6
.
1
0
.
1
1
4
44.71.100.85
44.96.10.
```

In essence, the print output should show me public IP addresses that do not have corresponding private IPs assigned.

Comment: what you want is not clear? you have public IP and private IP in all those jason list? and you want to loop through all of them?

Comment: Sorry. I've edited it and made it more clear. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my sample json:

```
json = {
    "Addresses": [
        {
            "PublicIp": "120.34.250.81",
            "AllocationId": "eipalloc-12345678901234567",
            "AssociationId": "eipassoc-12345678901234567",
            "Domain": "vpc",
            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-12345678901234567",
            "NetworkInterfaceOwnerId": "848293479",
            "PrivateIpAddress": "192.168.40.12",
            "PublicIpv4Pool": "amazon"
        },
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-10982738475698765",
            "PublicIp": "3.201.99.99",
            "AllocationId": "eipalloc-12345678901234567",
            "AssociationId": "eipassoc-12345678901234567",
            "Domain": "vpc",
            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-12345678901234567",
            "NetworkInterfaceOwnerId": "812942397874",
            "PrivateIpAddress": "44.12.3.3",
            "PublicIpv4Pool": "amazon"
        },
        {
            "PublicIp": "3.12.1.4",
            "AllocationId": "eipalloc-12897647827389876",
            "AssociationId": "eipassoc-95748298758423987",
            "Domain": "vpc",
            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-94872390876543212",
            "NetworkInterfaceOwnerId": "1209182938",
            #"PrivateIpAddress": "44.12.12.12",
            "PublicIpv4Pool": "amazon"
        }
    ]
}
```

and test code:

```
for item in json['Addresses']:
    if item.get('PrivateIpAddress') is None: print(item['PublicIp'])
```

the result is as follows.

```
3.12.1.4
```

Comment: There is actually. You can allocate Elastic IPs and not assign them to a private so you always have some available. Consider the use case where you no longer need a public elastic so you disassociate it with the private. That elastic IP still stays in your "account".

Comment: That is really good information. Thanks to knowing that. :) I have deleted the comment.

Comment: BTW, thank you so much. It seems like you made a very simple answer that works. I always overthink code I guess... but I'm new to Python as well, so... thanks again.

Comment: Oh and another note. I believe AWS still charges you for that assigned Elastic... nice of them huh? LOL...